# Publish Web App (MVC) to Azure (Blue azure screen)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, azure-web-app-service, publishing

I have been struggling for days now with this and do not understand neither can i find the cause of my problem. I have a ASP MVC web app with a Class library and the default web project, i am using Entity Framework.

I am getting this Azure blue default screen when publishing my app:
[image]

while when creating a new web app, also using entity framework i don't have this issue and the web app launches correctly to the Index page.

I do not understand what is happening and how i can fix this ...
I tried importing the profile from azure and also creating it from VS but same results ...
Any suggestion is welcome, thank you in advance!
Kind regards

Comment: Could you find your project in the Kudu console?

Comment: Yes i can, don't know nothing about that subject though :s

Comment: Check this link whether helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec8e519e-0cad-46b6-bdb0-4519cfed76f4/mvc-5-app-with-syncfusion-controls-wont-load-after-visual-studio-publish-blue-congrtulations

Comment: i have checked the Kudu link but can't find anything relevant to my problem, and the checklist they described in the beginning is OK on my side. The publish console in VS can't reveal anything (for me) that can help me trace the cause of this...

Comment: Try building it from the branch you are working on in the VSTS or Azure DevOps. I am pretty sure there is an error while building the solution.

Comment: @VikasSharma, i have no experience with this but i tried it (if i understand correctly what you are talking about) and it builded succesfully, see this: https://ibb.co/cfNLMp , or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i started comparing the new web app that did work and my app which didn't and turns out these little sections in the Web.config where causing the issue:

```
<system.webServer>

<!--<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  -->
</handlers>-->

</system.webServer>
```

Don't know how they got there but comment those and it works ...
Case closed!